# Convert factor to character, retain displayed information?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape swedish municipal election data, and need to count the parties in the municipal councils. Since there are local parties, the information is displayed with all the major parties in separate cells, but the smaller local parties are bunched together in a separate column.

When I scrape the table, and clean out to only the information I need, the variable is a factor, something I have encountered before and usually just convert to a character instead.

However, when I do this here, it destroys the information I want to retain.

Instead of showing "VÄG=3" for Borås "kommun", it shows "c(ÖVR = 9)" and deletes the information I needed, while the observations I would like to be NA's turn into "c(ÖVR = 1)".

I have also tried sub() in an attempt to replace the blank observations with NA's before trying to convert to characters, but then everything turns to NA's instead.

While a minimal reproducible sample is the best with simulated data, I cannot think of a way to reproduce this without also including the source, but if anyone knows a way, please tell me for future questions!

```r
library(rvest) #For Web scraping
library(tidyverse) #For mainly pipes and filter function

#Official Swedish Election data
url <-"https://data.val.se/val/val2006/slutlig_ovrigt/statistik/kommun/mandat_kommun_parti.html" 
elections <- read_html(url) %>%
     html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
elections <- elections[[1]]

# This is three different municipalities, one with one local party,
# one with no local party, and one with two local parties        
elections <- elections %>% filter(Kommun %in% c("Borås", "Eskilstuna", "Huddinge")) 

elections <- t(elections) #transpose so each municipality is a variable, and the parties are observations

elections <- elections[-nrow(elections),] #delete the total number of seats
elections <- elections[-1,] #Remove the municipalities  names
elections <- data.frame(elections) #convert into a data frame
row.names(elections) <- c() #remove the row names

others <- elections[nrow(elections),] #take the other parties
others <- as.character(others) #here everything goes wrong
```

The expected result for me would to convert it to the displayed information but as characters, instead of factor levels, and the empty observations would turn into NA's or something I could convert to NA's, but instead it turns into... this "c(ÖVR = X)"-format.

Any help or guidance to where I can find information on how to solve this would be much appreciated! The same goes with any critique on how to improve my question making!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few inadvisable steps to your current approach.  Consider this alternative which keeps the data in a tidy format:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url <-"https://data.val.se/val/val2006/slutlig_ovrigt/statistik/kommun/mandat_kommun_parti.html" #Official Swedish Election data

page <- read_html(url) 

page %>%
  html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE) %>%
  first()  %>% 
  filter(Kommun %in% c("Borås", "Eskilstuna", "Huddinge")) %>%
  select(Kommun, x = ÖVR) %>%  # renamed ÖVR as encoding was producing weird results with separate_rows() 
  separate_rows(x, sep = ", ") %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  group_by(Kommun) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(!is.na(x)))

  # A tibble: 3 x 2
  Kommun     Count
  <chr>      <int>
1 Borås          1
2 Eskilstuna     0
3 Huddinge       2
```

The main issue in your original approach is that `t()` makes your data a character matrix and then `data.frame()` by default converts strings to factors, which you later try to convert to a character on the data.frame object instead of each variable individually. So instead you can do:

```
elections <- t(elections) #transpose so each municipality is a variable, and the parties are observations
elections <- elections[-nrow(elections),] #delete the total number of seats
elections <- elections[-1,] #Remove the municipalities  names
elections <- data.frame(elections, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL) #convert into a data frame
others <- elections[nrow(elections),] #take the other parties
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'd rather not separate the rows, since I'm going to count all the parties in every municipality the past 20 years, and keeping a single municipality on a single row helps a lot. But you have given me a lot of help, so I should probably be able to figure this out, thanks! :)

Comment: @LeoCarlsson - See updated answer for alternative.  Also, having the data in long format won't prevent counting all the parties by municipality, rather it probably makes things easier.

Comment: @H 1 - Right now I'm first calculating the the number of local parties using str_count() to count the "="-signs, and then the numbers of major parties by checking the count of non-NA's per row. This worked until I realised that they in 2010 started reporting single local parties as "14(DEM)" instead of "DEM = 14". Using your method, how would you collapse the given example so it reads "Borås 1, Eskilstuna 0, Huddinge 2"? Again, thank you very much! I'm still a beginner who started learning R this summer, and I'm learning a lot from your help!

Comment: Super! This is very tidy and readable code, thank you for your help!